# Express-session not persisting after Nodemon restart

Tags: node.js, express, nodemon, express-session

I am using express-session and Nodemon. Anytime I save a change to the codebase Nodemon restarts the server and I lose my session. I am using connect-mongodb-session for the session store and it creates the session in the database just fine, but it does not seem to be working 100% since I am losing the session on server restart. After a server restart when I visit a route and log the sessionID it is a completely new session. Here is where I have the session setup:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
require('./db/mongoose');
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');
const session = require('express-session');
const MongoDBStore = require('connect-mongodb-session')(session);
const userRouter = require('./routes/userRoutes');
const apiRouter = require('./routes/apiRoutes');

app.use(express.json());

// Setup MongoDB to use as session store
const store = new MongoDBStore(
    {
        uri: process.env.MONGODB_CONNECT,
        collection: 'sessions'
    },
    function (err) {
        console.log('MongoDBStore connection error');
    }
);

// Setup express-session 
app.use(session({
    genid: function () {
        return uuidv4();
    },
    cookie: {
        maxAge: 60 * 1000 * 60 * 24 * 7, //Expires after 1 week
        secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? true : false,
        httpOnly: true
    },
    name: 'pchef' + uuidv4(),
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: store
}));

// Setup routes
app.use(userRouter);
app.use(apiRouter);

// Serve frontend if in production
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'frontend', 'build')))

    app.get('*', (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'frontend', 'build', 'index.html'))
    })
}

// Set up server listening
const PORT = process.env.PORT;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server up on ${PORT}`);
})
```

Comment: try without `name: 'pchef' + uuidv4(),`

Comment: Thanks! I just figure that out via trial and error and was coming back to add that to my post. Not sure why using the name field messes everything up, I'm assuming it is because I was using a dynamic name instead of a constant one.

Comment: is pretty obvious, uuidv4() gets invoked on boot and returns a random uuid

Comment: Yeah, I understand what I was doing in the name field. I guess I was thinking the name field wasn't that important and that sessions were ID'ed/validated/whatever off their sessionID. TDIL the name field plays a part in that as well.

Comment: yeah rtm the `name` property, `name: 'pchef'` on its own should be fine if needed at alll, it no less secure to leave it as-is, just not with the random uuid on each restart. The name is the name of the session cookie, if you change it on each start it won't match so the code wont see the cookie, also if you look at your browser your see a bunch of redundant session cookies, plus each one will be being sent up to the server.